# how to create a dotted line at a specific location in photoshop

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, line-art

I created this:
[image]

As you can see there is a fine line in this picture that is slightly darker than the rest (this will indicate the folding line in the end). I created it by making a rectangle with the `Marquee Tool`, then I clicked on `Image > Adjustments > Exposure` and then I set the `Gamma Correction` to `0.55`.

I want exactly this line as a dotted line and at a very specific place (specific coordinates) and specific height.

I managed to get the height correctly by carefully drawing. I'm struggling with the specific coordinates, I tried changing the y coordinate in the Canvas property on the right, but that actually cut out the rectangle and pasted it at a different location, similar to the selection tool in paint.

Additionally, I don't know how to turn this rectangle into a dotted line.

How can I achieve this?

I also have Illustrator if that is easier.

Edit: What's important is that I can set the exposure of the line so that it "blends" in with the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the **Pen Tool**.

[image]

Click once to create a start anchor... hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down and click again to create an end anchor. The <kbd>Shift</kbd> key will draw a straight 90° or 45° path (whichever is closer) between the anchors.

Draw a path and then set the *options* in the **Control Bar**...

[image]

You can adjust the stroke to many things...

[image]

[image]

You can then move this path to anywhere you need.

Comment: Thanks, I did this but then I cannot change the exposure, I don't want a simple dotted line, the dotted line is supposed to "blend" in with the background, sorry should have clarified that

Comment: You can change the blending mode of the layer with the line... you can also position the layer, convert it to a smart object, then `Command/Ctrl`-click the layer thumbnail to load a selection for an adjustment layer.

Comment: that worked, thanks !